# How to stop tags within a div from affecting elements outside a div?

Tags: html

So, on my website, I have user generated content. I have a wysiwyg editor, but there is a view source part. I have a few approved tags.

But it occurred to me, what if a user just puts  in without closing it? Then the rest of the rest of the page.
How can I get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I actaully wanted to tell you look how wordpress does this untill i tested it and found out that wordpress does not care ^^ i can break my page easy by open divs and not colosing them

anyway i found this.

```
/** * close all open xhtml tags at the end of the string
 * * @param string $html
 * @return string
 * @author Milian <mail@mili.de>
 */function closetags($html) {
  #put all opened tags into an array
  preg_match_all('#<([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result);
  $openedtags = $result[1];   #put all closed tags into an array
  preg_match_all('#</([a-z]+)>#iU', $html, $result);
  $closedtags = $result[1];
  $len_opened = count($openedtags);
  # all tags are closed
  if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) {
    return $html;
  }
  $openedtags = array_reverse($openedtags);
  # close tags
  for ($i=0; $i < $len_opened; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)){
      $html .= '</'.$openedtags[$i].'>';
    } else {
      unset($closedtags[array_search($openedtags[$i], $closedtags)]);    }
  }  return $html;}
```

this should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex topic in general and there's no easy shortcut. Before you start reinventing the wheel, use a library that has been designed to do exactly that. Supposedly [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is one of the few, if not the only, libraries that gets it right.